# Issue installing prestashop module : mymodule(class missing in /...)

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm new to prestashop module development and I can't seem to make it work. I followed a tutorial step by step but when I install the module, I always get this "Mymodule (class missing in /modules/Mymodule/test-module.php)".

I checked on the net and it seems this error happens when the php file isn't encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, but even doing this doesn't work.

Here is my code, hope someone finds what's the issue :

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

class CookiesPresta extends Module {
  public function __construct() {
   $this->name = 'CookiesPresta';
   $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
   $this->version = '1.0';
   $this->author = 'me myself';
   $this->need_instance = 0;
   $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.5');
   $this->dependencies = array();

   parent::__construct();

   $this->displayName = $this->l('Bandeau Cookies');
   $this->description = $this->l('Créez et personnalisez votre bandeau d\'information sur les cookies');

$this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Voulez vous désinstaller le module Bandeau Cookies');

if (!Configuration::get('cookiespresta'))      
  $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
}


public function install() {
 if (!parent::install()
        || !$this->registerHook('displayHeader')
        || !$this->registerHook('displayFooter')
    )
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function uninstall() {
   if(parent::uninstall())
      return false;
 return true;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This should be the structure: `modules/cookiespresta/`, `modules/cookiespresta/cookiespresta.php`, `$this->name = 'cookiespresta'`. Notice the lowercase letters and filenames. Are you following this naming standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your module as for Class name `CookiesPresta` you should name the directory `/cookiespresta` and your Class file `/cookiespresta/cookiespresta.php`

Comment: I've done this and I think that's what made it work, maybe. Or it might as well be the missing .xml file... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The xml file is only needed for the module page in BackOffice it would not throw an error on the FrontEnd. Could you please accept this answer if it solved your problem ? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [generator](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) of Prestashop to create a standard module